# dim an array gives mismatch error (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create an array of 9 variants but when I run the script I get an error "Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
      Description: Type mismatch:'aaxisarray1'
       "

```
Dim aaxisarray1(8)
aaxisarray1(0) = 0
aaxisarray1(1) = 0.000000
aaxisarray1(2) = z
aaxisarray1(3) = 1.000000
aaxisarray1(4) = 0.000000
aaxisarray1(5) = z
aaxisarray1(6) = 0.000000
aaxisarray1(7) = 1.000000
aaxisarray1(8) = z
```

I do not see how this is a type mismatch. This might be due to my inexperience as I have just started using VBScript for a couple days now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Above lines of your code generates no errors, please check other lines of your script as well.

Comment: It was somewhere else. Thank you for looking anyway. Sorry for my mistake